# Задать перемещение скролла

Tags: jquery, прокрутка

Когда мы находимся вверху страницы `[.scrollTop() = 0]`, нужно назначить на скролл колеса мыши фиксированное перемещение (например 50пх). Дальше скролл колесиком должен происходить стандартно. Но только если мы опять поднимаемся на верх страницы `[.scrollTop() = 0]`, снова назначается фиксированное перемещение после первого скролла колесиком вниз.

Спасибо.

Comment: А что это значит? Как это поведение должно выглядеть? Кручу колесо вниз, и он прыгает на 50px?

Comment: @goddan, какая-то бредовая задача, но еще хуже, что я повёлся на эту чушь. )) Угадал или нет, но предположу, что вы хотели [что-то в этом роде][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/4cpsLke3/

Comment: eicto, да. кручу колесо с любой "силой" - а прыгает (перемещаеться страница) только на 50пх

Comment: @Deonis, должно при любом скроле перемещать на 50пх. В твоем примере если сильнее "скрольнуть" ), то перепрыгивает 50пх.